# cant setup an active admin resource form with has many :through assoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a rails (3.7.8) app and using active admin to manage resources for the ff models:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_article_categories, :include => :article_categories  
  has_many :article_categories, :through => :user_article_categories, 
:source => :admin_user  
  has_many :articles, :through => :user_article_categories, 
:source => :admin_user
  # ...
end


class UserArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_user
  belongs_to :article_category
  attr_accessible :admin_user_id, :article_category_id, :included
  attr_accessor :included
  after_find :set_included

  private

  def set_included
    self.included = "1"
  end
  # ...
end
```

the "included" attribute was based on a solution [presented here](http://tech.thereq.com/post/12671192370/rails3-forms-for-has-many-through-and-nested-models)

```
class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_article_categories, :include => :admin_users
  has_many :admin_users, :through => :user_article_categories, 
:source => :article_category
  has_many :articles, :through => :user_article_categories, 
:source => :article_category
  # ...    
end
```

but I seem not to get setting up (correctly) a form for admin_users, such that creating a new admin_user would have all article_categories displayed as a list of checkboxes

while a persisted admin_user for update would have all article_categories checkboxes displayed but wit all previously set article-categories checked, so that an update would remove unchecked checkboxes and add newly checked ones to what goes to the join-table

for admin/admin_users.rb I create the form as follows, this does not work, though it renders correctly, any help will be appreciated

```
form do |f|
  if f.object.persisted? and current_admin_user.id == f.object.id
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.inputs :for => user_article_categories do |usr_art_catr|
        usr_art_catr.input :article_category_id, :hidden
        usr_art_catr.input :included
      end
    end
  else
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :superuser, :label => "Super User Priveleges"
      f.input :article_categories, :as => :check_boxes, 
    :collection => ArticleCategory.select("id, name")
    end
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to display a list of checkboxes of all article_categories and check all already checked article categories for a given admin_user on update.

Formtastic, when rendering the show form for the form's object, calls a method provided on the form object via

```
f.input :method_to_be_called, :as => :checkboxes
```

which formtastic would compare its result with a collection provided via 
the

```
:collection => any_valid_ruby_object
```

but both should return the same kinds; array/array or hash/hash, whatever, to determine which checkboxes should be checked, by performing a difference on the two collections.

The method called by formtastic could be an instance method on admin_user that queries the join-table, to determine which checkboxes should be checked and builds an array of that from the related article_categories table or returns an empty array when there is none.

This allows formtastic do what is right, as least in this context. This solution makes the "included" attribute on user_article_categories (the join-table) redundant!